# Loading excel column data using C# in a dropdown menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

I want to load a column in excel into a selectable dropdown menu using c#. I have access to the file, and can load the file in C#, but am not sure how to implement what I want. Suggestions? (I'm using Visual Studio 2008)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the OleDb Managed Data Provider to read an Excel spreadsheet using ADO.NET just like you would with a database.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\Book1.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO'";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();                
    //Where [F1] = column one, [F2] = column two etc, etc.
    OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select [F1] AS [id] from [Sheet1$]",conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}

listBox1.DataSource = dt;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "id";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a PIA solution something like this (assuming 5 items in column "A" of the first worksheet):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

...

worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;

Excel.Range range;
range = worksheet.get_Range("A1", "A5") as Excel.Range;
foreach (Excel.Range cell in range.Cells)
{
    myComboBox.Items.Add(cell.Value2 as string);
}
```

If you don't know the exact number if items in the dropdown at runtime, you will need to search the range to find the end; check out this sample [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_23167324.html).

This sample uses the Office 2007 PIAs, if you are using an older version the syntax should be very close but might vary a bit.

Comment: This method seems like it would be quite inefficient though if I wanted to add a dropdown to all cells in column 'A'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you only have a couple of options:

- [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57(VS.80).aspx) (PIA) that let you read and write from the Excel object model.
- Building a [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905533.aspx) (VSTO) solution, which effectively lets you write 'code behind' for your Excel spreadsheet. Depending on what you are trying to achieve this can make sense if you are actually doing a lot of work within excel, and your current application is really just creating an extension to the spreadsheet UI.